# How do I get the time an hour from now for my 12 hour time format in string?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-timepicker, android-date

I am planning to add an hour to the current time, which I have converted into a 12 hour format. Just not sure how to go about it. I want to keep mins the same, just want to add an hour, say the time is 11:59am -> I would like to show 12:59pm, or if the time is 5:20, I would like to show 6:20 and so on. 
Here's my code so far :

```
if (mDate.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
            am_pm = "AM";
        else if (mDate.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
            am_pm = "PM";


        String strHrsToShow = (mDate.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ? "12" : mDate.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "";
        String strMinsToShow = (mDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) < 10 ? "0" + mDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) : "" + mDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        mRegisterGuestStartTime.setText(String.format("%s:%s %s", strHrsToShow, strMinsToShow, am_pm));
```

Any ideas how to go about it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mDate` is a `Calendar` object I assume. If yes, why don't you use `Calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1)`? Doing it in String manipulation way lost the precision of the date/time value. You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the Calendar afterward

```
    // add an hour to the date
    mDate.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

    // prepare datetime formatter, sample output: "11:35 AM"
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
    mRegisterGuestStartTime.setText(timeFormat.format(mDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: can you explain with an example or alter my code to update that scenario

Comment: Updated the answer. SimpleDateFormat help you to print the desire date format with ease. With it, you can get rid of the if statement to get the AM/PM , or 24-hour roundup issue.
Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mr Brickowski. I actually needed :        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a",Locale.US);
 That did the trick.Thanks for the step in the right direction!